# Convert all dates stored in custom field

Tags: custom-field, date

I have a custom field to store the date of games, and I store it in database like

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

Now I need to convert all dates to

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

So how can do that?

Is timestamp a solution for it, if yes, how can do that

I need to change all old data to new data for 200 posts

Comment: Are you talking about custom fields? If so, you should store dates as `yyyy/mm/dd`

Comment: yes, before i store as yyyy/dd/mm but now i change it to yyyy/mm/dd, but old data i need to change it

Comment: Use `date()` in conjunction with `strtotime()`. [Click](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#100144)

Comment: @dingo_d how can change old data ?

Comment: `$new_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($old_time));`, where `$old_time` is the value of your date from where ever you are pulling it from (database I presume).

Comment: ok now you are convert it , but how can i get $old_time ? i need to change date not time , and how update old value

Comment: Please prperly [edit] your question with these new info about format and that you need this for custom fields

Answer (score 1):

Find the correct key for `game_date_key` and run this once:

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts" WHERE post_type='post');
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $old_date = get_post_meta($post->ID,'game_date_key',true);
    $new_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($old_date));
    update_post_meta($post->ID,'game_date_key',$new_date,$old_date);
}
```

(I assume you will have the sense to backup your database first just in case. :-)

Comment: nice.. but some time i store in mm/dd/yyyy what can i do ?

Comment: pick one format and stick to it (the new is more international), you can always convert it back a similar way after retrieving it if need be.